# Decide which Enum return based on object properties

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns, enums

I'm wondering if there is some design pattern to help me with this problem.

Let's say I have a class `Person` which has three attributes: `name`, `nickname` and `speaksEnglish` and an Enum `PersonType` with `TypeOne`, `TypeTwo` and `TypeThree`.

Let's say if a `Person` has `nickname` and `speaksEnglish` it's a `TypeOne`. If it has `nickame` but doesn't `speaksEnglish`, it's a `TypeTwo`. If it does not have `nickame`, so it's `TypeThree`.

My first thought would have a method with some `if-else` and returning the related `Enum`. In the future I can have more attributes in `Person` and other types of `PersonType` to decide.

So, my first thought was create a method with a bunch of `if (...) { return <PersonType> }` or `switch-case`, but I was wondering if there is some design pattern I can use instead of `ifs` and `switch-case`.

Comment: What about add an abstract method to Enum, let's say method 'boolean test(Person)', so that each Enum type is able to check if the person is of that type. Later you just need to iterate through Enum.values() and call test(person). Not sure if is the best idea, but you will keep the logic in a single place e avoid all those if/else

Comment: Are your `Person` objects mutable or immutable?

Answer (score 0):

I will recomend you to use just simple inheritance with immutable objects.

So, at first you have to create abstract class:

```
public abstract class AbstractPerson {

    private final String name;
    private final Optional<String> nickname; 
    private final boolean speaksEnglish;
    private final PersonType personType;

    protected AbstractPerson(final String name, final Optional<String> nickname, final boolean speaksEnglish, final PersonType personType) {
        this.name = name;
        this.nickname = nickname;
        this.speaksEnglish = speaksEnglish;
        this.personType = personType;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public Optional<String> getNickname() {
        return nickname;
    }

    public boolean getSpeaksEnglish() {
        return speaksEnglish;
    }

    public PersonType getPersonType() {
        return personType;
    }

}
```

With `PersonType` enum:

```
public enum PersonType {

    TypeOne, TypeTwo, TypeThree;

}
```

Now, we have three options with corresponding constructors in child classes:

```
public final class EnglishSpeakingPerson extends AbstractPerson {

    public EnglishSpeakingPerson(final String name, final String nickname) {
        super(name, Optional.of(nickname), true, PersonType.TypeOne);
    }

}

public final class Person extends AbstractPerson {

    public Person(final String name, final String nickname) {
        super(name, Optional.of(nickname), false, PersonType.TypeTwo);
    }

    public Person(final String name) {
        super(name, Optional.empty(), false, PersonType.TypeThree);
    }

}
```

In this case, our concrete classes are immutable and its type is defined in moment of creation. You don't need to create if-else ladders - if you want to create new type, just create new class/constructor.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think `Type` can really be an attribute of a `Person`. I am not against @ByeBye's answer but with that implementation you will still end up changing `Person` class when there are new types introduced.

X type of person is ultimately a person itself. Say a `Manager` or `Developer` are both employees of a company, so it makes a lot of sense to have them as specialized classes that derive from an `Employee`. Similarly in your case, having person type as an attribute and then doing all if-else stuff clearly violates SOLID.

I would instead have specific implementations of `Person` class and mark itself as an abstract one.

```
public abstract class Person {
    public Person(string name) {
        Name = name;
    }
    public abstract string Name { get; set; }
    public abstract string NickName { get; set; }
    public abstract bool SpeaksEnglish { get; set; }
}

public class TypeOnePerson : Person {
    public TypeOnePerson(string name, string nickName) : base(name) {
        NickName = nickName; // Validate empty/ null 
    }
    SpeaksEnglish = true;
}

public class TypeTwoPerson : Person {
    public TypeOnePerson(string name, string nickName) : base(name) {
        NickName = nickName; // Validate empty/ null 
    }
    SpeaksEnglish = false;
}
```

I also think that this question is language-agnostic, it is a pure design question. So please bear with me as the code above is in C#. That doesn't matter, however.

Comment: I like your option, but I think that type has to be part of class - we have to avoid using constructs like `instanceOf`. It will be helpful if we want filter by type or something like that

Comment: You should not need to do `instanceOf` for type checking. Because all your code will talk to `Person` abstraction and not specific implementations. Specific implementations will only be injected where ever code expects `Person`.

Comment: But if you have list of `Person` and you want to filter only `TypeTwoPerson` you don't have such information

Answer (score 0):

As far as OO principles are considered why to create object with combinations of optional attributes? If its question of one or two then *Optional* approach will remain maintainable, but type will be based on many combinations (in future code will be full of Boolean Algebra) and question also says "*...In the future I can have more attributes in Person and other types of PersonType to decide.*".

I would suggest approach of using Decorator pattern, which allows us to create customized objects with complete code reuse. Person will be Component and Optional attributes (they are types e.g NickName with validation as behavior) will be concrete decorators.

Any *addition to Person* and *adding new Concrete Decorator* type remain two separate concerns. *Decorator Pattern* is a best candidate for this kind of requirement. Its Intent from GOF book (by Erich gamma) pattern Catalog says - "*Attach additional responsibilities to an object dynamically. Decorators provide a flexible alternative to subclassing for extending functionality*". [though for very small number of expected extensions earlier answers make more sense.]